# I can’t normally make authentication via django-allauth, how to fix the error?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

In general, I've been messing around with VK all day. I created an application in it, got all the keys, and inserted them. From my site, you can even go to authorization, but it asks if I allow access to the application, I say yes, and then this thing:

[image]

I can't find any information on the internet about this. There are no errors in the logs. Here are my connection settings.

**Aplications**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.steam',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.telegram',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
```

**django-allauth settings**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "users.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 10
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 3
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
    },
    'steam': {
        "APP": {
            "client_id": '',
            "secret": 'my_sret',
            "SCOPE": ["email"],
        }
    },
    'telegram': {
        'TOKEN': 'my_token'
    },
    'vk': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': 'my_client_id',
            'secret': 'my_secret',
            'key': 'my_key'
        },
        "SCOPE": ["email"],
        "FIELDS": ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    }

}
```

**AUTH_BACKENDS**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

**My custom adapter**

```
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def populate_user(self, request, sociallogin, data):
        user = super().populate_user(request, sociallogin, data)

        if data.get('first_name') and data.get('last_name'):
            user.username = '@' + str(data['first_name'] + data['last_name']).lower()
        elif data.get('full_name'):
            user.username = '@' + str(data['full_name']).lower().replace(' ', '')
        elif data.get('name'):
            user.username = '@' + str(data['name']).lower()
        elif data.get('username'):
            user.username = '@' + str(data['username']).lower()
        user.username = User.objects.generate_username(data['email'])
        return user
    
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        if sociallogin.account.provider == 'vk':
            user = request.user
            user.is_vk_authenticated = True
            user.save()
            return None
        return super().pre_social_login(request, sociallogin)
```

**Here are my application settings in VK**

[image]

**Here is the social application setting in the Django admin**

[image]

**I WILL BE VERY GRATEFUL FOR YOUR HELP!!!!!!!**

I've already searched the entire Internet, I tried to do it in another project, but it's always the same. In general, I can not come to a normal solution to this problem. Even ChatGPT doesn't help :(